# Enforcing scalebox placement

Tags: positioning

Im using a scalebox and it happened to be put onto a empty page, with no text else.
how can i enforce it to placed earlier, so i dont only the scalebox on a page.
or do you think that does look acceptable?

Comment: We need more context, preferably something we can replicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\scalebox` has no positional code at all. It is positioned in exactly the same way as a letter `x` is positioned, and placed according to the current line and page breaking. It is never moved in the way `figure` or `table` environments are moved.

Comment: i indeed had it inside a figure environemnt. sorry for wasting your time.